# Является ли словосочетание "Первое знакомство" плеоназмом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, недопустимая-метка

Например. Мое **первое знакомство** с  творчеством Льва Толстого  состоялось еще в дошкольном детстве.

Answer (score 2):

Это не плеоназм:

*Мое **первое знакомство** с творчеством Льва Толстого состоялось еще в дошкольном детстве.*

**[Карта слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)**

**ЗНАКОМСТВО,** 4. с чем. **Наличие знаний, обладание сведениями о чём-л.** З. с деревней, окрестностями. З. с сельским хозяйством. З. с историей, с литературой, с живописью. ◊ Шапочное знакомство. Самое поверхностное, случайное.

Первое знакомство — это **начальные знания**, которые мы получаем о каком-либо предмете или лице. В дальнейшем они **дополняются** новыми сведениями.

Answer (score 0):

Одно дело говорить о человеке как личности (*Так состоялось наше с Ольгой знакомство*; *Дальнейшее знакомство подтвердит*; *Давнее, почти тридцатилетнее знакомство*). Другое — о творчестве, выраженном в ряде произведений автора (*Первое знакомство с американской прозой*; *Первое знакомство с текстами Цветаевой*). Толстой представляет собой классический пример такого авторства; наследие его велико и разнообразно, это романы, повести, притчи, пьесы, переводы, трактаты, статьи.

Answer (score 0):

**Анализ плеоназма**

Чтобы определить, является ли выражение **"первое знакомство"** плеоназмом или нет, необходимо провести анализ его составных частей.

1. "Первое" - указывает на первый в какой-то последовательности, что на говорит о том, что может быть несколько знакомств у человека.
2. "Знакомство" - процесс знакомства с кем-либо или чем-либо.
   Анализируя данные части, можно прийти к выводу, что **"первое знакомство"** не является плеоназмом.

**Объяснение**

В выражении "первое знакомство" оба компонента имеют отличное значение друг от друга. "Первое" указывает на порядковый номер, тогда как **"знакомство"** относится к процессу вступления в контакт с незнакомым предметом или человеком. Таким образом, **"первое знакомство"** выражает первичное событие, первый раз, когда кто-то знакомится с чем-то или с кем-то новым.
Примеры использования
1.*Она волновалась перед своим первым знакомством с будущим мужем."*
2."*Моё первое знакомство с искусством произошло в музее современного искусства."*
3.  *"Первое знакомство с новым городом может быть захватывающим опытом."*

**Заключение**

Выражение **"первое знакомство"** не является плеоназмом. Его составные части, "первое" и "знакомство", имеют разные значения и выражают конкретные аспекты процесса начального знакомства человека с кем-то или чем-то новым. Оно используется в повседневной речи и литературе для передачи смысла первого вступления в контакт, создавая четкую и понятную формулировку.

Comment: Зачем так длинно)  Мы же не роботы.  Словаря вполне достаточно.